# Unable to compare last word in the file

Tags: java, tokenize, readline

I have been trying to compare the input file with the database file. The code compares the files and outputs the words from the input file(test.txt) that are present in the database file(db.txt). But however I am not getting the last word from the input file in the output.

test.txt contains:

```
There is a book on the table
```

db.txt contains:

```
book 
the 
table
```

Thus here I am not getting table in the output.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File file = new File("G:\\Project\\test.txt");
        File file2 = new File("G:\\Project\\db.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(line);
            stringBuffer.append("\n");
        }
        fileReader.close();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(stringBuffer.toString()," ");
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) 
        {
            String word=st.nextToken();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2)); 
            String lin;

            while((lin=br.readLine())!=null){
                { if(word.equalsIgnoreCase(lin))
                    System.out.println(word);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output received:

```
book
the
```

What is it that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending newline character to `stringbuffer` and that is causing this issue.

Remove below line from your code and try, it will work.

`stringBuffer.append("\n");`